# Print nested Firebase object in Angular using Angularfire lib

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a Firebase structure like this:

```
"warehouses": {
    "warehouse1": {
        "floor_sales": {
            "!-K3cC1LZL_aRVWG2fVHJ" : true,
            "-K3cKKgci7r8fNEjHLfn" : true
        }
    }
}
"sales": {
    "warehouse1": {
        "!-K3cC1LZL_aRVWG2fVHJ" : {
            "amount" : "19"
            "kgs": "2"
        },
        "-K3cKKgci7r8fNEjHLfn" : {
            "amount" : "50"
            "kgs": "5"
        }
    }
    "warehouse2": {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am able to get all sales by warehouse with $firebaseArray(FBObj.child('sales' + warehouseId));

If I get the sales from a service like this $firebaseArray(FBObj.child('sales');

I get all the sales but each sale is inside a warehouse like this:

```
0: Object
    $$hashKey: "object:86"
    $id: "warehouse1"
    $priority: null
    -K3VaYVQGgeB2fDV94DY: Object
    -K3WCyxVoIxXkrDq2UCA: Object
    -K3WDDdEt_Lvyh5DDbqG: Object
    __proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
$$added: ()
$$error: ()
...
```

I need to get all the sales not only from a warehouse.
Does anyone know a way to get all sales (not only from a warehouse) to print them in a view? 
Should I get the sales in another way from Firebase?
Should I print the sales in Angular in another way?

I tried to change Firebase structure to save all sales without warehouseId but then I do not have a way to get all floor_sales using Angularfire.

Any help would be very helpful thank you.

Comment: looks like you want to achieve relational data queries like in SQL using JSON ?

Comment: In NoSQL you often store the data in the format that is most suitable for how you need to use it. So when you say "I need to get all the sales not only from a warehouse", you should probably not store the sales for each warehouse separately but (also) keep the transaction in one list. But how long do you expect that list to get? Won't displaying all those item on all clients be a performance drain?